# Cannot compare the values of two columns correctly using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with several columns and about 22,000 rows. My goal is to determine if each row equals the maximum value of that row. I do so by creating a dummy variable column.

Here is an example of the data.

[image]

Here is the code I have. `testdf` is the dataframe and `test2` is the output.

Please excuse the fact that the third and fourth rows do the same thing as the fifth row's command. I had tried it manually to keep my own sanity.

```
test2 = testdf %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(New_Column_1 = max(Column_C)) %>% 
  mutate(New_Column_2 = if_else(Column_C == New_Column_1, "Yes", "No")) %>% # the previous and this line execute the next line manually
  mutate(`Final?` = case_when( # this method still doesn't work
    Column_C == max(Column_C) ~ "Y",
    TRUE ~ "N"
  ))
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Since all the numbers in `Column_C` are the same, I expected for all rows to return a "Y" or "Yes". However, only the seventh and twelfth rows returned a "Y" or "Yes" in columns "Final?" and "New_Column_2."

Even more weirdly, when I tried to create a reproducible example using `dput` and ran the same code, the results were correct. Here is the result after running the same code on the dataframe created using `dput`.

[image]

I'm not sure why the reproducible example doesn't behave incorrectly and if the reproducible dataframe will be useful, but here it is below anyway.

```
testdf_dput = structure(list(Column_A = 1:12, Column_B = c(458, 458, 458, 458, 
438, 407, 382, 355, 345, 338, 322, 307), Column_C = c(458, 458, 
458, 458, 458, 458, 458, 458, 458, 458, 458, 458), Column_D = c(531, 
531, 531, 531, 531, 531, 531, 531, 531, 531, 531, 531), Column_E = c(181833.517467249, 
181833.517467249, 181833.517467249, 181833.517467249, 188243.751141552, 
193750.334152334, 198517.429319372, 201049.918309859, 203428.110144927, 
205612.289940828, 205185.167701863, 206427.749185668), Column_F = c("Melissa", 
"Dominique", "Ronald", "Jedediah", "Samantha", "Justin", "Jeanmarc", 
"Tiffany", "Jacob", "David", "Schyanne", "Vincent"), Column_G = c("2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)

test3 = testdf_dput %>% 
  mutate(New_Column_1 = max(Column_C)) %>% 
  mutate(New_Column_2 = if_else(Column_C == New_Column_1, "Yes", "No")) %>% # the previous and this line execute the next line manually
  mutate(`Final?` = case_when( # this method still doesn't work
    Column_C == max(Column_C) ~ "Y",
    TRUE ~ "N"
  ))
```

Please let me know if you've experienced something like this. I have no idea what is going on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Tee, please do not upload [data screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557), it is hard to answer a question in that manner.

Comment: Thanks for the note. However, the reproducible sample (in the post) does not lead to the error. Is there another way I can showcase my issue without screenshots?

Comment: I guess that perhaps you've a problem with floating point. For example `c(3.0000000001, 3) == max(c(3.0000000001, 3))` gives TRUE FALSE even when both numbers are printed as 3 3. Also, as you say your dataset is 22.000 rows long, the sample does not reflect the max(Column_C).

Comment: Can you `dput(max(testdf$Column_C))`?

Comment: @RicVillalba, thanks for the answers. `dput(max(testdf$Column_C))` returns `458`, which would suggest a floating point isn't the issue. However, I ran `mutate(Column_C = round(Column_C, 0)` before the other commands and results turned out correctly (i.e., the `New_Column_2` and `Final?` columns all return `Yes" and `Y`). Do you know this may be?

Comment: My thought is that some of the numbers may be very close to 458 (e.g., 457.9999999999), which then don't work. However, that must mean `dput` rounds the numbers. However, I wasn't able to confirm this after a google search.

Comment: what with `dput(max(testdf$Column_C[testdf$Column_C != 458]))`? Before you apply round, of course.

Comment: Hey @RicVillalba, thanks for the comment. I ended up rounding the values to the nearest digit and the functions worked. It is good enough. Thanks for your help!